# Problems finding messages when compiling ROS project

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've been having some problems lately with ROS and catkin_make. Whenever I compile the whole project cmake struggles to find certain messages. I would paste the errors codes but they are just like "package/msg.h not found". The weird thing is that after trying to compile the project 3 or 4 times for some reason the compiler is able to end up finding everything and the whole thing works.

I would like to solve this issue, whoever after spending some days studying cmake and package files I could not find the source of the problem, does anyone know how could I track down this bug? I've been able to isolate this problem to one package, and the only different thing from the rest is that I compiled it with the c++11 flag.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357447/problems-finding-messages-when-compiling-ros-project/) by [lavnir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53924/lavnir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

since your information provided is quite sparse I'm not certain in the answer. However I'm assuming your messages are defined in the same package as your node. Have you checked that your include directiories are set

```
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

and your dependencies are set to include ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} to make sure your messages are built before your node/library...

```
add_dependencies(my_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

---

Originally posted by [ipa-jba](https://answers.ros.org/users/3541/ipa-jba/) with karma: 153 on 2020-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lavnir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53924/lavnir/) on 2020-07-18**:
Thanks! That was it, just missed to add the dependencies so that msgs are built before the rest.